# How to insert a number in correct position of a list racket?

Tags: list, racket, rkt

Suppose you insert (15) if I run this program, the output will be (14 16 17 18 19)
How can I make the program to insert the number 15 in the correct position (pos = 1) or any number (n) in it's correct position (pos).

```
(define list1 '(14 16 17 18 19))

(define lst (list))
(define (insert lst n)
  (if (empty? lst)
      '()
      (foldr cons (list n) lst))) ;The value gets inserted at the end of the list
```

Comment: Why not just `cons` and then `sort` the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have many sorting algorithm like Quicksort, histogram sort, bubble sort.

You can see this [Sorting Algorithms](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Category:Sorting_Algorithms) or wikipedia.

If `n` is bigger than every data inside list which is `lst` become `'()` we just return `(list n)`

e.g. `(f '() 1) -> '(1)`

When `n` less or equal to first element we insert in first position.

e.g. `(f '(2) 1) -> (cons 1 '(2))`

If not we want data like this:
`(f '(1 2 4) 3) -> (cons 1 (f '(2 4) 3)) -> (cons 1 (cons 2 (f '(4) 3))) -> (cons 1 (cons 2 (cons 3 '(4)))) -> (list 1 2 3 4)`

```
(define (insert-with-<-order lst n)
  (cond
    [(empty? lst)
     (list n)]
    [(<= n (first lst))
     (cons n lst)]
    [else
     (cons (first lst)
           (insert-with-<-order (rest lst) n))]))

(insert-with-<-order '(1 1 2 3) 1.5)
(insert-with-<-order '(-2 0.5 1 2 5) 0.1)
(insert-with-<-order '(1 2 3) 4)
```

Use `sort`

```
(define (insert-with-order lst n)
  (sort (cons n lst) <))

(insert-with-order '(14 16 17 18 19) 15)
```